# How can i create activex using C#

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2013, activex

I want to create an ActiveX interface with two input controls (say name and address), how can i create it using C#? I have a simple "Hello world application" but no idea about creating ActiveX with input controls...

Is it possible to create ActiveX with input control?

Comment: I don't think so, it's more specific because it's asking also for windows form, probably there are other duplicates.